# Angular JS ng-class-odd in nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to develop a very generic table outputter - no set number of rows or columns.  As such, I've got nested ng-repeat attributes, as such:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList">
        <td ng-repeat="col in colList">{{printCell(row,col)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's working great!  Until I try to use `ng-class-even` and `ng-class-odd` to change the background color of the rows accordingly.

If I put the `ng-class-***` statements on the `td` tag, I get alternating column colors.

If I put the `ng-class-***` statements on the `tr` tag, I don't get *any* class assignment - they all stay default.

I want alternating row colors.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The value of `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` can be a string: `ng-class-odd="'myClass'"` or an expression `ng-class-odd="{myClass: boolExpression}"`

Also:

Angular 1.2+: `ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}"`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList" ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}">
        <td ng-repeat="col in colList">{{printCell(row,col)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
```

Angular < 1.2 `ng-class="{even: !($index%2), odd: ($index%2)}"`

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList" ng-class="{even: !($index%2), odd: ($index%2)}">
        <td ng-repeat="col in colList">{{printCell(row,col)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/JYn7S/1/

Comment: Thank you for the info on using `ng-class` instead of `ng-class-even` and `ng-class-odd`.  However, in this situation, the problem was not in the angularjs, but in the css - I'd specified the classes as td.even and td.odd, so they weren't showing up on the tr tag.