# ngClassOdd/ngClassEven not working as expected

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-class-even, angularjs-ng-class-odd

Using Angular version 1.2.15, I found a bug that it seems started on version 1.2.2 until 1.2.15.

[Plunker Demo to reproduce](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nExMtZ92AQS7BvLsQ8m?p=preview)

**Html**

```
<body ng-app="">
     <ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz','Felipe','Vero']">
     <li ng-repeat="name in names">
      <span ng-class-odd="'shared odd'" ng-class-even="'shared even'">
        {{name}}
      </span>
     </li>
   </ol>
</body
```

**CSS**

```
 .shared {color: red;}
 .even{ background-color:yellow; }
 .odd{ background-color:white; }
```

You will see how the odd style does not work on the 3rd Element.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

If not what would make more sense upgrade or downgrade?

Comment: It looks like it works only if one of style is applied. A probable workaround is to set the even style as default and then change it for odd rows (or vice versa).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was a known bug and has been fixed, so why not update to `v1.2.16` ?
It works as expected on `v1.2.16`.

If you want to stay on `v1.2.15` you should either use Morgan's solution (`ng-class` + `$index`), or include only one class in `ngClassOdd`/`ngClassEven`:

```
<span class="shared" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
```

---

BTW, there were no breaking changes in version 1.2.16 (according to the **[changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-1.2.16)**), so upgrading should be totally transparent.

---

**UPDATE:**

For the sake of completeness, I should mention there is the option of using `ngRepeat`'s `$even`/`$odd` properties. E.g.:

```
<span ng-class="$even?'shared odd':'shared even'">
```

<sub>**Note:**

Since the list of items displayed by `ngRepeat` is 0-based, the 1st element (`$index: 0`) is considered odd, while we (humans) expect the 1st element to be considered even. So, make sure you apply the classes "inversely".

The same is true for the `ngClass + $index` approach.</sub>

---

The recommended solution is still to upgrade to `v1.2.16`.
Just in case, **[here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HuCSxoLxEBb6PFacpIVx?p=preview)** with all 3 `v1.2.15` solutions.

Comment: Well I guess he's got the options he's looking for now, I'm curious to see what he picks.

Comment: @MorganDelaney: We had forgotten about the `$even`/`$odd` properties exposed by `ngRepeat`. I think **now** OP has all available options :)

Comment: it looks like upgrading is the safer/correct approach since it is a minor upgrade

Comment: Yup ! I am all into upgrading ! (I used `v1.3.0-beta.7` on my latest production project - but don't tell my boss :P)

Answer (score 4):

From your Plunkr, it looks like you're simply not getting that "shared" class in there.

An alternative could be to use `ng-class` in conjunction with `$index`

[Here's an example on Plunkr which checks to see if $index is divisible by 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/wHienF2fNZh96fl41dJn?p=preview)

`<span ng-class="{ even: !($index % 2), odd: !!($index % 2) }" class="shared">`

Answer (score 0):

```
**The value of `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` can be a string: `ng-class-odd="'myClass'"` or an expression `ng-class-odd="{myClass: boolExpression}"`**

Also:

**Angular 1.2+**: `ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}"`

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">
           <span> ng-class="{even: $shared even, odd: `enter code here`$shared odd}">{{name}}</span>

        </tr>
    </ul>
    <hr />

**Angular < 1.2** `ng-class="{even: !($index%2), odd: ($index%2)}"`
```

Comment: Humm, that's a copy and paste of another thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725832/angular-js-ng-class-odd-in-nested-ng-repeats