# How can I make odd even rows to be in different colors in accordion bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I use accordion in my angularjs project.

I want to make headers rows in accordion even odd diffrent color.

Here  is my view template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="accordionWrapper">
        <accordion close-others="true">
            <!-- All Remaining Groups -->
            <accordion-group ng-repeat="inspection in inspections.inspectionsDamage" is-open="isOpen" >
                <accordion-heading>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <strong>{{inspection.inspItemDesc}}</strong>
                        <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isOpen}"></i>
                    </div>
                </accordion-heading>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 small">
                    <label>fix type: </label> {{inspection.inspItemDesc}}<br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><hr></div>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

And here is my desired view:

[image]

I tryed to add this rows :

```
ng-class-odd="'blueStyle'" 

ng-class-even="'greenStyle'"
```

To this row:

```
 <accordion-group ng-repeat="inspection in inspections.inspectionsDamage" is-open="isOpen" >
```

But I didn't get desired result.

Any idea How can I make odd even rows to be in diffrent colors in accordion bootstrap?

Comment: You have access to the `$index` for which you could determine if the modulus of the index equals 0 or not, and return the CSS class fit for the even or odd rows... so maybe like `ng-class= $root.isEven($index) ? ng-class-even : ng-class-odd` and in your controller `$scope.isEven = function(index) { return n % 2 == 0; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With  [CSS3 nth-child() selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp),something like this should work:

```
accordion-group:nth-child(odd) {
/*background: #ff0000; your style here*/
}

accordion-group:nth-child(even) {
/*background: #0000ff;your style here*/
}
```

**Update:**

But as Micheal said it doesn't work ! Because there is no `<accoridon-group >` tag at all , instead code below will be generated:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" heading="Dynamic Group Header - 1" ng-repeat="group in groups">
   <div class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)">
      <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
       ...
   </div>
  </div>
```

So we have `.panel-default` and `.panel-heading`:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading:nth-child(odd){
   background:#00f5f5;
}
```

Up to now our styling works **but** due to **nth-child CSS selector hierarchy issues** all our  target elements will be affected .
We have to act better:

```
.panel-default:nth-of-type(odd) .panel-heading{
  background:#00f5f5;
}
```

It works as charm.
More about [nth-of-type()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

Comment: @Michael please follow the link above there are 3 examples: [1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child),[2](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even),[3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_formula)

Comment: I marked your solution, before I check it  but, unfortunately it not works.

Comment: I suspect that there must be another problem with your styling , are you sure it is OK @Michael? did you looked at the links?

Comment: Can you make it work on this example : http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelKut/68gk8/220/   ?

Comment: of course :) I updated [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68gk8/231/) and will update the answer too , sorry  made a little mistake @Michael I will explain ,and I do apologize

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for Odd row color class
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

Refer this for Even row color class
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven)

Similar answer in Stackoverflow
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725832/angular-js-ng-class-odd-in-nested-ng-repeats)

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` attributes work with the standard Bootstrap 3.3.6 CSS classes.

```
ng-class-odd="'panel-info'"      <!-- blue panel class -->

ng-class-even="'panel-success'"  <!-- green panel class -->

<uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups" 
     ng-class-odd="'panel-info'"  ng-class-even="'panel-success'">
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/UTCufgnqYQeApN4tY8cS?p=preview).

Comment: What do you mean 'dynamic created accordian'?